# Selecting enum values based on key names

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have an enum like so:

```
public enum Animals 
{ 
    CatOne = 12, 
    CatTwo = 13, 
    CatThree = 14, 
    DogOne = 21, 
    DogTwo = 22 
};
```

Great.

Now I want to get the values of all the cats.. What I'm trying to do is this:

```
public static int[] GetCatValues()
{

    List<int> catValues = new List<int>();

    foreach(var cat in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Animals)))
    {
        Animals animal;

        if(cat.StartsWith("Cat"))
        {
            Enum.TryParse(cat, out animal);
            catValues.Add((int)animal);
        }       
    }

    return catValues.ToArray();
}
```

Which works okay. Except it looks ugly. Why can't I do something like

```
Animals
    .Select(r => (int)r)
    .Where(r => r.StartsWith("Cat"))
    .ToArray();
```

I know that doesn't work. So  is there a better way of getting all values of enum that starts with certain string.

I know I could probably use regex to avoid false positives, but, I am keeping it simple for now.

Thanks.

Comment: r.ToString().StartsWith("Cat"))

Comment: Why are you trying to get the value of all dogs by looking for entries that start with `cat`?

Comment: why would you want to use RegEx you can accomplish this using `Linq`

Comment: @MattBurland, oops, I was building the question as I typed so it's a brin-fo (similar to typo but with a misstep in my brain)

Comment: @DJKRAZE Can I? I did not know that, this is what I'm trying to find out here!

Comment: `Jon Skeet` has a great example not to mention he's comes with a `Wealth of knowledge`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a compromise set of code - it's not as clean as what you're looking for, but it's far better than the foreach loop version.

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Animals)).OfType<Animals>()
    .Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith("Cat"))
    .Select(x => (int)x).ToArray();
```

Comment: Now I am confused what answer I should accept, this or Jon Skeet's

Comment: @LocustHorde - I'd love if you accepted mine, since I arrived at this answer first, but Jon's is *far* more comprehensive and has a useful link that I'm going to be following up on, so I'd probably suggest his.  The general rule is "Whichever helped more", I believe, so that's your call to make.

Comment: I ended up using this answer before Jon Skeet's version of this came up, (later modified with Jon Skeet's suggestion of ``Cast`` instead of ``OfType``) so I am choosing this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Well the simplest approach is simply to get the name using `ToString`:

```
return ((Animals[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(Animals)))
    .Where(r => r.ToString().StartsWith("Cat"))
    .Select(r => (int) r) // Assuming you want this
    .ToArray();
```

Or using `Cast<>` to avoid the cast to `Animals[]`:

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Animals))
    .Cast<Animals>()
    .Where(r => r.ToString().StartsWith("Cat"))
    .Select(r => (int) r) // Assuming you want this
    .ToArray();
```

(I prefer `Cast<>` to `OfType<>` here as we really *are* expecting every value to be `Animals` - if anything isn't, an exception is entirely appropriate!)

However, this all feels slightly icky to me - attaching any importance to the names of enum values always feels a little bit hairy, and parsing specific bits of the name even more so. You might want to try decorating each value with an attribute to specify a "group".

I'd also suggest calling the enum `Animal` rather than `Animals` - only flag-based enums should generally be plural, and "a collection of `Animals` values" sounds distinctly odd.

(Also, you may want to look at my [Unconstrained Melody](https://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) project which allows for type-safe, efficient generic access to enums, via generic constraints which are legal in IL but can't be expressed in C#...)

Comment: I don't think you can call `.Where()` on an enum type directly.   `Animals.Where()` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Bobson: Doh, I'd assumed `Animals` was already a property returning all the animals. Editing...

Comment: Enums support ``.Where()`` ?!

Comment: @LocustHorde: Nope, but arrays of enums do :) See my edited version.

Comment: @jon, how would one use `.Where()` on an enum?

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg: As edited a while ago, not on the enum type itself, but on the values.

Comment: @JonSkeet, there needs to be an extra parantheses around the first line else the return is trying to return ``Animals[]`` itself.. so first line = ``return ((Animals[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Animals))).Where....``

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks, this works okay, now looking at your unconstrained melody project!

Comment: @Bobson: I've now included a version using `Cast` - and my reasoning for `Cast` over `OfType`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Good reasoning.  And I definitely agree about deriving meaning from the name of the enum.

Comment: @JonSkeet, wow, thanks, definitely learnt a lot here. This was just an example, but even so, I would have used ``Animals`` if I were to code it.. thanks. Also, I hate this whole bit too - I know what you mean by extracting meanings from the enum, but I just inherited this code from my team leader and I couldn't talk him to allow me to rewrite his code so I am adding some utility methods to extend the functionality - team leaders reason being we are going to abandon the project soon so it's not worth a rewrite; so this is more of a shortcut..so it will have to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do this would be by using flags.

```
[Flags]
public enum Animals 
{ 
    CatOne = 1, 
    CatTwo = 2, 
    CatThree = 4, 
    DogOne = 8, 
    DogTwo = 16,
    AllCats = Animals.CatOne | Animals.CatTwo | Animals.CatThree,
    AllDogs = Animals.DogOne | Animals.DogTwo 
};
```

Of course, this will only work if you are able to renumber your enum, and without knowing exactly what you need to do with these values it's hard to say if it would suit you or not.

Comment: ... Sorry, how would I be able to get values of all cats with this one?!

Comment: Oh, I need to compare my enum value with the ``AllCats`` value.. hm, I'm trying to do something slightly different so I'd need to get an intersection of two enums so this wouldn't suit my purpose for now!

Comment: The values of all cats are in `AllCats`. They are `OR`ed together. To test if a particular value is a cat you would do something like `Animals.AllCats & myValue == myValue`. This will evaluate as true if `myValue` is a cat.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but I am supposed to get all values and perform an intersection with another enum so for this case at least it's not acceptable.. But thanks for this, I didn't know I could OR it! +1

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat ugly, but might suit your case:

In this case, the cats will be the actual Enums and not integers.

```
var cats = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Animals))
    .Where (e => e.StartsWith("Cat"))
    .Select (e => Enum.Parse(typeof(Animals), e));
```