# Condition for enum values in java

Tags: java, enums, conditional-statements

I wanted to know how to have an enum in java, containing values that could adjust depending on the condition.

Exemple :

```
Public enum values{
    If (condition){
    A("a", 1),
    B("b",2);
    } else {
    C("c", 1);
    }
    
    Private string value;
    Private int id;
    
    values(string value, int id) {
    this.value = value;
    this.id = id;
    }
    }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Enums map constant values. You should put your conditional outside an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the purpose of `Enum`. From [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

> An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be
> a set of predefined constants. The variable must be equal to one of
> the values that have been predefined for it.

You can add the logic in method,

```
if (condition) 
    value = values.A;
else
   value = values.C;
```

You can also use `filter` on enum,

```
Arrays.stream(values.values())
        .filter(condition)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thank you, so if I want then to use only certain values of the enum for a specific use , is it better to define a hole new enum ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: I find this very interesting, it may solve my problem: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365395/selecting-enum-values-based-on-key-names&ved=2ahUKEwiq8eLfjcDqAhUnxIUKHRooANYQjjgwAHoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2XrgD5IvMWEUnYE9bdknT7&cshid=1594296291891.   What do you think about it please ?

Comment: That is not for java. You can do something like, ```Arrays.stream(values.values())
        .filter(condition)
        .collect(toList());```

I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I was wondering if the filter could be the name of the enumeration value (A or B or C )?

Comment: That would be your `condition` that you were using in enum `If (condition)`

Comment: Arrays.stream(values.values())
        .filter(condition)
        .collect(toList()); ..  Can you post the working code for this scenario.